# Save video frame in JPEG XR (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm new in C# coding and I would like to save a video frame in Jpeg-XR (16-bits image).
I wrote some lines of code that should be close to the solution but I'm only able to correctly save a 8-bits image.

```
//Use Windows.Media.Editing to get ImageStream
            var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);
            var composition = new MediaComposition();
            composition.Clips.Add(clip);

            var imageStream = await composition.GetThumbnailAsync(Position, (int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);

            //generate bitmap 
            var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)frameWidth, (int)frameHeight);
            writableBitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

            //generate some random name for file in PicturesLibrary
            var name = Position.Minutes.ToString() + "_" + Position.Seconds.ToString() + "_"+ Position.Milliseconds.ToString();
            var saveAsTarget = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(name + file.DisplayName + ".jxr");

            //get stream from bitmap
            const int BytesPerPixel = 4;
            Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
            byte[] pixels = new byte[(int)frameWidth * (int)frameHeight * BytesPerPixel];

            await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

            using (var writeStream = await saveAsTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegXREncoderId, writeStream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(
                    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                    BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                    (uint)writableBitmap.PixelWidth,
                    (uint)writableBitmap.PixelHeight,
                    96.0,
                    96.0,
                    pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();

                using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
```

I tried to set the BitmapPixelFormat to Rgba16 but the results is a wrongly encoded image. Any clue on how to solve my problems?

Alternative solutions to my current code are welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do that much pixel copying by hand, this example uses the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace. I have no idea if that is available in uwp or not:

```
public static void SaveJxr(this BitmapSource bitmap, Stream stream, byte qualityLevel = 80)
{
    var encoder = new WmpBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.QualityLevel = qualityLevel;
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

This uses the Windows Media Photo encoder, and but as far as I can tell this is just an older name for Jpeg XR. I'm also fairly sure the produced images was actually 16bits when I tested this. But you also need a tool that can decode 16 bit images, and these do not seem very common.

If you control both the saving and reading side you might consider using [JpegLS](https://github.com/team-charls/charls-native-dotnet) instead, at least that seem to give better results for mono16 images when I tested it.

Comment: Thank you for answering but, unfortunately, this solution is not available in UWP